# How to serve https Aurelia from development

Tags: windows, https, development-environment, aurelia

I am using Microsoft Code and Aurelia-CLI and have a simple initial hello world project.

```
au run --watch
```

... serves the project over http

how can I serve it over https in development environment.

I am using Windows 10

Comment: To clarify, serve over HTTPS not http

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `https: true` to browserSync: `aurelia_project/tasks/run.js`

```
browserSync({
   https: true,
   ....
```

tested this on Linux only.

Comment: Thanks for this, now I just have to cope with self certificates and getting them to work in development on chrome (Windows10).  Works find in IE, Edge.